# Check first two digit number lies between 00 && 99

Tags: java, android

I develop a function that reject number starting with 00  and 99.

```
public Boolean valideCode(EditText code_postal){

    String number =     code_postal.getText().toString();

    if (number.charAt(0)==00){


    }

    return false;

}
```

How can i implement this function properly.

Comment: Just to clarify - you want `valideCode` to return `false` if and only if the string starts with '00' and '99'? We can ignore non-numeric text, etc, for simplicity?

Comment: @Dimitri feel free to accept one of the above answers in case one of them was helpful. Regards

Answer (score 3):

Use `.startsWith()`:

```
if (number.startsWith("00") || number.startsWith("99")) ...
```

`.charAt()` returns a single character, not a string.

(out of sheer curiosity, why this? `code_postal.getText().toString();` From the name of `.getText()`, you'd have figured out that it already returned a `String`... Bah.)

**EDIT** So, on demand, another version which checks by converting to an int first...

```
final int begin = Integer.parseInt(number.subString(0, 2));
if (begin % 99 == 0) // can only be true if number is 0 or 99
    // etc
```

Comment: did you ever read the question? does your condition check numbers in between?

Comment: @Pankaj: The title and the description are completly different. Title: All numbers between. Description: Numbers startsWith

Comment: @StefanBeike I agreed. But he should make clear about the confusion right? He is having too many points that means he is vary good SO, so he should make clear first :D

Comment: @PankajKumar I don't understand the problem, honestly? For one, you cannot have a "number starting with 00" except if in String form.

Comment: @PankajKumar what is more, it is a postal code, so in string form to begin with! This seems to be in France, I'm French, and a "code postal" like 06707 is valid.

Comment: Thats the reason I was asking u? I thought you have more idea

Comment: @PankajKumar well, yes, but is that relevant? That's another question

Comment: @PankajKumar anyway, now I have a number check :p

Comment: :D don't know. We are solving an unsolvable question :D. only Dimitri can solve this problem that what he want. right?

Answer (score 3):

that if statement will always returns false.

One solution:

```
if (number.trim().startsWith("00") || number.trim().startsWith("99")){
  System.out.println("not valid");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String` class [indexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) method :

```
if (number.indexOf("00")==0 || number.indexOf("99")==0)
```

**EDITED: -** You need this as I understood from your question subject line *"Check first two digit number lies between 00 && 99".*

```
public static boolean isValid(String name) {
    boolean isValid = true;
    if(name.length()>2){
        name = name.substring(0, 2);
    }
    try {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(name);
        if(number>-1 || number<100){
            isValid = false;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        isValid = false;
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: @fge You are correct , but that came to my mind because I use `indexOf()` more often than `startsWith()` and I'm not an expert of the API .

Comment: Note: that should be `.subString(0, 2)`, the substring is up to the index of the second argument minus 1

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question specially heading "lies between 00 && 99" you want this

```
    try
    {
       String s = "45Abc";
       Integer i = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0,2));
        if (i>00 && i<99)
            System.out.println("True");

    }catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("First two characters are not numbers");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use your logic look like below

```
private boolean isValid(String str) {
        if (str == null)
            return false; 

        String tempStr = null;
        try {
            if (str.length() > 2) {
                tempStr = str.substring(0, 2);
            } else {
                tempStr = str; 
            }

            int number = Integer.parseInt(tempStr);
            if (number >= 0 && number <= 99) {
                return false; //in between 0 to 99
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Instead of `if (a && b) return false; else return true;` you could just `return !a && !b;`

Comment: like `return !(number >= 0 && number <= 99)`? yes you are 200% correct.

Answer (score 1):

> **To check if the Entered number starts with "00" or "99"**

```
 public Boolean valideCode(EditText code_postal){

    String number = code_postal.getText().toString();

    if(number.startsWith("00") || number.startsWith("99")){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

> **To check if the Entered number is between "00" and "99"**

```
public Boolean valideCode(EditText code_postal){

    String number = code_postal.getText().toString();
    String firstTwoDigits = number.substring(0,2);

    if (Integer.valueOf(firstTwoDigits )>=0 && Integer.valueOf(firstTwoDigits )<=99){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Note:** The title of your question and description are different. hence two answers.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be different (and inefficient and impenetrable):

```
return !number.matches("^\s?(00|99).+");
```